# How can I highlight regex matches in Python?

Tags: python, editor

How might I highlight the matches in regex in the sentence? I figure that I could use the locations of the matches like I would get from this:

```
s = "This is a sentence where I talk about interesting stuff like sencha tea."
spans = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(r'sen\w+', s)]
```

But how do I force the terminal to change the colors of those spans during the output of that string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To colour text you can use ANSI Escape codes.  In python you would do the following to change the colour of the text from that point onwards.

```
print '\033[' + str(code) + 'm'
```

Where code is a value from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes).  Note that 0 will reset any changes, and 30-37 are colours.  So basically you want to insert '\033[' + str(code) + 'm' before a match and '\033[0m' afterwards to reset your terminal.  For example the following should result in all of your terminal's colours being printed:

```
print 'break'.join('\033[{0}mcolour\33[0m'.format(i) for i in range(30, 38))
```

The following is a messy example of what you asked for

```
import re
colourFormat = '\033[{0}m'
colourStr = colourFormat.format(32)
resetStr = colourFormat.format(0)
s = "This is a sentence where I talk about interesting stuff like sencha tea."

lastMatch = 0
formattedText = ''
for match in re.finditer(r'sen\w+', s):
    start, end = match.span()
    formattedText += s[lastMatch: start]
    formattedText += colourStr
    formattedText += s[start: end]
    formattedText += resetStr
    lastMatch = end
formattedText += s[lastMatch:]

print formattedText
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than it needs to be. Please see my (revised) answer.

Answer (score 15):

There are several terminal color packages available such as [termstyle](https://github.com/gfxmonk/termstyle) or [termcolor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor).  I like [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), which works on Windows as well.

Here's an example of doing what you want with colorama:

```
from colorama import init, Fore
import re

init() # only necessary on Windows
s = "This is a sentence where I talk about interesting stuff like sencha tea."
print(re.sub(r'(sen\w+)', Fore.RED + r'\1' + Fore.RESET, s))
```